# Android - Collapsing Toolbar Like WhatsApp - blink issue in API 24

Tags: java, android, android-7.0-nougat

I am creating view like WhatsApp collapsing toolbar. It has Blink Issue in SDK-API 24, but works fine in API 23.

I am using [CollapsingToolBarLikeWhatsApp](https://github.com/StartingAndroid/CollapsingToolbarLikeWhatsAPP)

Could anyone help me to fix this issue? Thanks